# Redirect existing github pages site to custom domain without breaking links

Tags: redirects, dns, http, github

I have my blog hosted at `https://example.github.io` and it's been around for a while - and search engines etc. have indexed the pages.

I want to keep hosting the site on github pages (for now) but I want the move the site behind a custom domain.

I know you can setup a CNAME for custom domains on github pages - however it looks like once you do that, github will stop serving the contents from `https://example.github.io` and just issue a 404 instead, with no opportunity to issue a redirect, so any existing links to the blog will be broken.

Is there any clean way of resolving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference I followed the guide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167113/redirect-github-pages-to-custom-domain @chad-dupuis suggested.

This meant adding `rel=canonical` link tags and meta refresh tags (with 5 second grace period) to the github pages version of my site, changing any links to articles to the new URL, along with adding a notice at the top to say the site had moved and will no longer be updated.

It will have to do, not ideal but a good enough compromise

Answer (score 1):

I have my personal blog hosted at gitlab with a custom domain and it is available at both domains after I created the custom domain.  I thought it would redirect and perhaps there is a way to do that, but it seems to simply appear at both.

There may be some type of fix for that by now, but there is an old forum post discussing javascript solutions to this (go all the way to the bottom) https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/302 .  I haven't tried any of these, but that seems sensible enought to me.

Comment: Git*Hub* and Git*Lab* are not the same thing though

Comment: I did misread it, but the issue appears to be the same on both gitlab and github and the solution would be platform agnostic either way...  Here's another discussion regarding github specifically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167113/redirect-github-pages-to-custom-domain that has some other options.